# Counting rows without any NaNs in a struct

Tags: arrays, matlab, struct

I need to count how many structs do not have any NaNs across all fields in an array of structures. The sample struct looks like this:

```
a(1).b = 11;
a(2).b = NaN;
a(3).b = 22;
a(4).b = 33;
a(1).c = 44;
a(2).c = 55;
a(3).c = 66;
a(4).c = NaN;
```

The output looks like this

```
Fields    b     c

1         44    11
2         55    NaN
3         66    22
4         NaN   33
```

The structs without NaNs are 1 and 3, so there should be 2 in total here.

I tried using `size(a, 2)`, but it just tells me the total number of structs in the array. I need it to calculate *N* (the number of observations in the sample). NaNs don't count as observations as they are omitted in the analysis.

What is the simplest way to count structs without any NaNs in a struct array?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest using the following one-line command:

```
nnz(~any(cellfun(@isnan,struct2cell(a))))
```

`struct2cell(a)` converts your struct into the 3D cell array
`cellfun(@isnan,___)` applies `isnan` to each element of cell array
`~any(__)` works along first dimension and returns arrays that have no NaNs
`nnz(__)` counts how many rows have no NaNs

The result is just a number, `2` in this case.

The following:

```
find(~any(cellfun(@isnan,struct2cell(a))))
```

Would tell you which rows are without NaNs

Comment: This one is great! Lacks knowing which ones, but very nice +1

Comment: @AnderBiguri thanks for the remark, added the finding the row indices

Comment: Good suggestion @Daniel .

Comment: I deleted my comment because to my surprise it was slower. My suggestion was `find(~any(isnan(cell2mat(struct2cell(a)))))`.

Answer (score 5):

This will tell you which ones have no NaNs

```
for ii=1:size(a,2)
    hasNoNaNs(ii)=~any(structfun(@isnan,a(ii)));
end
```

The way it works is iterates trhoug each of the structures, and use `structfun` to call `isnan` in each of the elements of it, then checks if `any` of them is a `NaN` and negates the result, thus giving 1 in the ones that have no `NaN`s

Comment: I don't know if it's necessarily faster, but it does read better to replace your `sum` by `any`. You avoid switching the type from logical to double and then back to logical.

Comment: @craigim definetly a smarter way! thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 4):

Because [`bsxfun`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) is never the wrong approach!

```
sum(all(bsxfun(@le,cell2mat(struct2cell(a)),inf)))
```

---

**How this works:**

This converts the struct to a cell, and then to a matrix:

```
cell2mat(struct2cell(a))
ans(:,:,1) =
    11
    44
ans(:,:,2) =
   NaN
    55
ans(:,:,3) =
    22
    66
ans(:,:,4) =
    33
   NaN
```

Then it uses `bsxfun` to check which of those elements are less than, or equal to zero. The only value that doesn't satisfy this condition is `NaN`.

```
bsxfun(@le,cell2mat(struct2cell(a)),inf)
ans(:,:,1) =
     1
     1
ans(:,:,2) =
     0
     1
ans(:,:,3) =
     1
     1
ans(:,:,4) =
     1
     0
```

Then, we check if all the values in each of those slices are true:

```
all(bsxfun(@le,cell2mat(struct2cell(a)),inf))
ans(:,:,1) =
     1
ans(:,:,2) =
     0
ans(:,:,3) =
     1
ans(:,:,4) =
     0
```

And finally, we sum it up:

```
sum(all(bsxfun(@le,cell2mat(struct2cell(a)),inf)))
ans =
     2
```

(By the way: It's possible to just skip the `bsxfun`, but where's the fun in that)

```
sum(all(cell2mat(struct2cell(a))<=inf))
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`arrayfun`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) to iterate over `a` and [`structfun`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/structfun.html) to iterate over fields and you get a logical array of elements that do not have `NaN`s:

```
>> arrayfun(@(x) ~any(structfun(@isnan, x)), a)
ans =
     1     0     1     0
```

Now you can just `sum` it

```
>> sum(arrayfun(@(x) ~any(structfun(@isnan, x)), a))
ans =
     2
```

Answer (score 2):

Taking the idea from [this not working answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35155748/2732801) to use comma separated lists:

```
s=sum(~any(isnan([[a.b];[a.c]])));
```

It may look very dumb to hard-code the field names but it leads to fast code because it avoids both iterating and cell arrays.

Generalizing this approach to arbitriary field names, you end up with this solution:

```
n=true(size(a));
for f = fieldnames(a).'
    n(isnan([a.(f{1})]))=false;
end
n=sum(n(:));
```

Assuming that you have a large struct with only few fieldnames this is very efficient, because it is only iterating the fieldnames.

Comment: Even though I accepted brainkz's answer as suitable for this particular question, I ended up using your solution for my real data set because I have a field with string data-type there and `struct2cell` didn't work for it. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Third solution maybe - may not be elegant depending on your data:

```
A = [[a.b];[a.c]];  %//EDIT -- Fixed based on @Daniel's correct solution
IndNotNaN = find (~isnan(A));
```

Depends if you have lots of structs you will have to concatenate a.b, a.c ....a.n

Comment: Good Idea using comma separated lists here, but it is not working properly. I assume you tested with a size [n 1] struct, not with a [1 n] struct.

Comment: @Daniel ah, sorry, I was away, yes, the answer you provided is much better. I used a struct of [n 1].